# Mono - loading external dlls with it's dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I've got serious trouble with Mono behaviour. My application uses **System.Component.Composition** to load plugins. Those plugins are place in subfolder of my program. Let me show you:

```
+ProgramFolder
--Program.exe
--ProgramCore.dll
-+PluginsFolder
--+Plugin1Folder
----Plugin1.dll
----SomeLibrary.dll (it's dependence which is used by Plugin1.dll)
---Plugin2
```

And it works pretty well when runned in native windows environment. But as soon as I would like to run it in MONO environment it fails with error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Plugin1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In my app.config i placed in **assembly binding** section such probing

```
<probing privatePath="PluginsFolder/Plugin1Folder"/>
```

to allow my program search for dll's here but it looks that MONO ignore this section. How to make it work in MONO?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It's second time I see that MONO works totally diferrently than native Windows environment. I had to rewrite method and now, it works on both environments as expectected.

So this is that class with appropiate method:

```
class ModulesLoader
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(ISchedulable))]
    public IEnumerable<ISchedulable> Modules { get; set; }
    private string dir;
    private string name;

    public ModulesLoader(string directory, string name)
    {
        Assert.ThrowIfEmptyString(directory);
        Assert.ThrowIfNull (name);
        this.dir = directory;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        var assembly = GetType ().Assembly; //Assembly of our executable program
        var dllCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog (assembly);
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(dllCatalog);
        var pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom (Path.Combine (dir, name)); //We have to explicit point which assembly will be loaded
        var pluginCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog (pluginAssembly); //pass it to catalog to let framework know each vital information about this .dll
        catalog.Catalogs.Add (pluginCatalog);
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this); //and it works!
    }
}
```

There was second problem too. System.Configuration dll wasn't marked as 'Copy local' and MONO throws InvalidProgramException which inform that method body is empty. Finally, I get manage to make it work xD

Writing platform agnostic software sometimes is really weird xD